# Error: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i need to select the minimum auto-increment number, then select the id number for reference in selecting the student's info. here's what I've got:

```
strSQL = "SELECT min(number) from main_queue "
cmd = New MySqlCommand(strSQL, CONNECTION)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
If dr.HasRows Then
    dr.Read()
    Dim min As Integer
    min = dr("min(number)")
    strSQL = "SELECT idno_ from main_queue where number='" + min + "'"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(strSQL, CONNECTION)
    If dr.HasRows Then
        dr.Read()
        Dim idnum As Integer
        idnum = dr("idno_")
        strSQL = "SELECT * from student_records where number='" + idnum + "'"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(strSQL, CONNECTION)
        If dr.HasRows Then
            dr.Read()
            mon_name.Text = dr("name_")
            mon_IDno.Text = dr("IDno")
        End If
    End If
End If
```

I'm getting a "Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid." error at line where i select the id number using the minimum auto-increment number as the reference.

Comment: Try giving `min(number)` an alias, as in `SELECT min(number) AS min_number from main_queue` and fetch that instead.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson 
you mean...
`SELECT min(number) as min_number from main_queue;` then
`SELECT idno_ from main_queue as idnum where number= min_number;` then
`SELECT * from student_records where IDno=idnum;'`

i tried this code in workbench but it returns just the min_number

Comment: I meant using that query and `min = dr("min_number")`, however I agree with the answers below that it's probably simpler to do it in a single query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I don't understand correctly your database schema, but it seems that you could write it all in a single query

```
Dim strSQL = "SELECT * FROM student_records " & _
             "where idNO =  " & _
             "(SELECT idno_ from main_queue where number= " & _
             "(SELECT min(number) from main_queue))"
cmd = New MySqlCommand(strSQL, CONNECTION)
If dr.Read() Then
    mon_name.Text = dr("name_")
    mon_IDno.Text = dr("IDno")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

managed to make it work! here's my code

`SELECT * from student_records where IDno in (select idno_ from main_queue where number in (SELECT min(number) as min_number from main_queue))`

Comment: thanks everyone! i'll be asking more on my project =)

Comment: I don't understand the need of using IN. Apart from that your working solution is identical to my answer. Could you explain what happen if you use = instead of IN?

Comment: there's no difference in using in and "=" i figured it how before reading your answer. thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Well, then I suggest to give preference to the = version because (while I am no an expert) I think that it has better performances. Also, as a side note, please if any of the answers here are helpful I think you should upvote them and/or accept one of them as explained in the [about] page